# Admob rewarded videos taking too much storage space

Tags: android, admob, adcolony, applovin

I currently use AdMob to mediate RewardedVideo from AdColony and Applovin. The issue I am facing is that every time I open my app and load a new RewardedVideo, the persistent storage memory is being increased by about 7MB.

In the screenshot below: I cleared the persistent storage once, then opened my app, waited for a RewardedVideo to finished loading, then force closed my app and reopened it 12 times. Totalling a use of 67.73 MB.

[image: admob rewarded video storage issue]

My main issue is that I would like to save this chunk of data in the cache and not the persistent storage. The end user might want to clear the data in order to gain space, and will also lose other data that he will want to keep by doing so(login data / preferences).

Is there any way to tell AdMob to use the cache folder instead of the data folder ?

My second question is how can I reduce the amount of data used ? Can I tell AdMob to remove the data at some point ? If I load a new RewardedVideo, I don't need to keep the previous one. Should I do it programmatically ? (finding where AdMob saves its data)

Comment: [note: I'm speculating] Because of the way mediation works, the ads you show are loaded by the other networks' Android SDKs, the same as if you'd used them directly. AdMob doesn't really control how they're cached or even displayed (the mediation adapters call the same public API methods as everyone else). You'll probably have more luck if you can identify which network (AdColony or AppLovin) is the one caching ads like that, and look through their documentation to see if there's a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

As RedBrogdon is commenting, the cache mechanism is implemented by each of Ad Networks and AdMob has no abilities to control it. I have used AdColony many times and I think they don't have any options such as you want to. I don't have any ideas about Applovin, but I believe they both have the limitation of the size of caches.